# How to add a left padding to the WPF CheckBox control?

Tags: .net, wpf, checkbox, padding, controltemplate

Good day,

I'm in the process of styling a CheckBox control in an WPF application. My goal is to add a padding to the left of the CheckBox 'default' rectangle/border.

By default the padding is only applied to the content area of the CheckBox. Margin does work on the left, but in this case the CheckBox doesn't register the click to check the box.

Anyone got an idea? Thanks in advance!!

**Edit #1**, in answer to Vlad, an example which shows the difference in padding/margin:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
   <Border Width="400" Height="50" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
      <CheckBox Content="Normal, clickable everywhere" />
   </Border>
   <Border Width="400" Height="50" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
      <CheckBox Content="Content padding, clickable everywhere" Padding="5" />
   </Border>
   <Border Width="400" Height="50" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
      <CheckBox Content="Control margin, not clickable in area 5px around" Margin="5" />
   </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, `CheckBox` _with_ a margin works in a different way than _without_ it? Could you please post the (minimal) code reproducing that?

Comment: @Vlad, had my post editted with an example. Hope it's clear.

Comment: It is not possible to do so with the Build-in `ControlTemplate` of the `CheckBox`. You can create your own `ControlTemplate` for the CheckBox. Copy from here (.NET4) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Monty: see my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's expected to behave this way. Margin is considered to be "outside" of the control, so the margin area is not letting the clicks through to the control. The padding area, on the contrary, is considered to be the part of control (between the control itself and its "client area" where the content is rendered), so the padding area is getting the clicks.

It looks like you can go with just `Padding="5,0,0,0"`. (This adds padding only on the left side.) See [this picture](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC155786.png) about the WPF's box model.

---

Update: based on your comment, you need to hack the default template. The default template can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

You would need the following changes: include the `BulletDecorator` into a `Grid`, and set the desired margin to the `BulletDecorator`. This must help, as hopefully the focus will be applied to the whole `Grid` and not the `BulletDecorator`. Or, alternately, you can set the margin at the `BulletDecorator.Bullet`'s `Border`.

---

Update: Of course it's better for maintainability not to copy the whole template definition into the actual code. It can be avoided with the following trick.

Say you've decided to go for setting an additional margin at the `Bullet`'s `Border`. You can try to override the default style for `Border` *just within the `Checkbox`'s `Bullet`*. The following trick should do this:

```
<!-- first, define a style for border -->
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="MyCoolBorderWithMargin">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
</Style>

<!-- then, define a style for BulletDecorator -->
<!-- this style overrides the style for inner borders -->
<Style TargetType="BulletDecorator" x:Key="MyCoolDecoratorStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource MyCoolBorderWithMargin}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<!-- finally, override the style for CheckBox -->
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="BulletDecorator"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource MyCoolDecoratorStyle}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

This should help.

Beware that this code is a hack, using the knowledge about how the default control template for `CheckBox` is implemented in the current WPF version. (If you are using WPF version different from 4.0, you may need to update the code, as it's version-specific: different versions of WPF use different control templates!)

Comment: Thanks, I understand the designed behaviour. Unfortunately, the padding on the CheckBox control is only applied on the Content area. And the Content area is always positioned to the right of the clickable rectangle. So this is unfortunately not the solution...

Comment: @Monty: well, look at the second approach in the updated answer.

Comment: Okay, that's a shot! One remaining question, can I set the margin on the BulletDecorator (or Border) without copying the entire controltemplate to my code?

Comment: Great, that was the missing link!! Nice to notice it's still a hack, but acceptable in my opinion, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for `Margin` and not `Padding`. Have you found [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx#wcpsdk_layout_amp_padding_properties)? I think it gives quite a thorough explanation.

CheckBox with added whitespace on left side only:

```
<CheckBox Margin="50 0 0 0"/>
```

Comment: Check my post, I mentioned it doesn't register the click to check the CheckBox in the margin area. Also updated post with an example that shows this. Unfortunately not a solution.

Comment: @Monty: The reason the `CheckBox` doesnt register the click in the margin area is because its not part of the control. This can be changed but I would argue its bad interface design. Are you really sure you want to do this?

Comment: mizipzor, in this case yes. I only showed a part of my UI, the CheckBox is part of a styled ListBox. Hereby the missing clickable area on the left of the CheckBox works counter intuitive.